# Problemas com a conversão do Array em Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Com a atualização do swift3 estou a ter o seguinte erro "type 'Any' has no subscript members", já vi imensas perguntas sobre o assunto e testei a maior parte delas mas sem sucesso. O código onde estou a ter este erro é o seguinte:

```
 Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
                .responseJSON{
                    response in
                    if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {

                        let json = JSON(value)
                        for (index, subJson) in json {
                            self.addressArray.add(subJson.object)
                            let ind: Int = Int(index)!

                            let defaultvalue: Int = self.Array[ind]["IsDefault"] as? Int

                            if(defaultvalue == 1)
                            {
                                let prefs: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                                let ID: Int = self.Array[ind]["ID"] as! Int
                                let Name: String = self.Array[ind]["Tag"] as! String

                                prefs.set(addressName, forKey: "Name")
                                prefs.set(addressID, forKey: “ID")
                                prefs.synchronize()
                            }

                        }
                        self.listAddress.reloadData()
                    }
            }
```

Sendo que o erro está dar em todas as partes em que faço algo deste género `self.Array[ind]["IsDefault"] as? Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Troque:

```
let json = JSON(value)
```

Por:

```
let json = JSON(value) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

Você tem que fazer um cast do JSON para os tipos que você vai tratar no código.

Comment: fiz o que disse mas continuo com o mesmo erro nas linhas do tipo self.Array[ind]["IsDefault"] as? Int e agora no código que você disse aparece o seguinte aviso "Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type ''[String: AnyObject] always fails"